# Mostrar los posts correspondientes al usuario que está logueado (Wordpress - PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

Para mi proyecto web en Wordpress necesito habilitar un página donde los usuarios puedan ver los contenidos que ellos mismos han generado en la web (videos subidos, comentarios, eventos, etc), pero con la particularidad de que en esta página sólo se va a mostrar la información que ellos han generado y no la de otros usuarios. Es decir, lo que necesito es escribir el código para que solo se muestre la información generada por el usuario que está logeado. He hecho muchos intentos pero soy consciente de que no consigo concluir, correctamente, la última parte del código (o lo mejor hay algún error, también, en el resto) donde se tiene que incorporar la línea que te permita mostrar el resultado de lo que arroja el código:

1. ¿Es correcto hacerlo con ***echo***, ***return***? y aunque sea con uno u otro, ¿cómo debería ser esta línea de código? He hecho muchos intentos, pero sin éxito (ver código abajo).
2. ¿Tengo que emplear el comando ***function*** y ***add_filter*** en el código?
3. Si le pudieran echar un vistazo al fragmento de código mostrado abajo. Para su información, el resultado que me arroja este código en la página es ***Array***.
4. Les indico alguno enlaces donde he estado consultado sobre este tema:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Code_Documentation
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69614/logged-in-user-id-as-post-id
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685396/get-post-id-of-current-logged-in-user-and-add-a-link-to-the-menu

***Código:***

```
<?php // Accedemos a la variable global
global $current_user;
// Obtenemos la informacion del usuario conectado y asignamos los valores a 
las variables globales
// Mas info sobre 'get_currentuserinfo()': 
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo
get_currentuserinfo();
// Guardamos el nombre del usuario en una variable
$usuario = esc_attr($current_user->user_login);
$args = array(
'author'        =>  $current_user->ID, 
'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
'order'         =>  'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1 // no limit
);
$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
echo $args;
?>
```

Gracias!!

Comment: BUENOS DIAS BRO...hubieras editado la anterior pregunta en lugar de hacer otra..

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes un monton de preguntas sin respuestas aceptadas. Podes revisarlas y tomar una desicion respecto de ellas? Que es lo que te muestra y que queres que muestre y como?

Comment: @srJJ, disculpa, a qué te refieres cuando indicas "hubieras editado la anterior pregunta en lugar de hacer otra.." ¿he hecho dos?

Comment: @gbianchi, perfecto, reviso la preguntas y decido sobre su aceptación. Respecto a esta cuestión, por ejemplo, si un usuario sube videos a la web, necesito que vea, en una página concreto que destino al efecto, solo los videos que él ha subido, es decir, que sólo sea vean los videos del usuario que está logeado. En mi pregunta he explicado con detalle los intentos que he hecho.

Comment: El codigo debe ir en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creas una página con slug "listado" en el backend y luego en la carpeta del theme un archivo llamado `page-listado.php` (el título puede ser diferente, el contenido de la página lo mostramos al final de las listas)

```
<?php get_header(); // header del wordpress ?>
<?php if (get_the_content()) : ?>
 <h1><?php the_title(); // título de la página ?></h1>
        <?php
        global $current_user;
        if($current_user->ID != 0) : ?>
        <?php
        // parametros de query
        $the_args = array(
          'author'        =>  $current_user->ID,
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
          'order'         =>  'DESC',
          'posts_per_page' => 15, //-1,
          'offset'      =>   0,
        );
        // tipo POSTS
        $the_args['post_type']='post';
        $the_query = new WP_Query($the_args);
        ?>
        <?php if ($the_query-> have_posts ()) :?>
          <h2>posts</h2>
          <ul>
            <?php while ($the_query-> have_posts ()) : $the_query-> the_post(); ?>
              <li><?php the_date();?> - <a
                href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title()?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        // tipo PAGES
        $the_args['post_type']='page';
        $the_query = new WP_Query($the_args);
        ?>
        <?php if ($the_query-> have_posts ()) :?>
          <h2>pages</h2>
          <ul>
            <?php while ($the_query-> have_posts ()) : $the_query-> the_post(); ?>
              <li><?php the_date();?> - <a
                href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title()?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        // tipo ATTACHMENTS
        $the_args['post_type']='attachment';
        $the_args['post_status']='inherit';
        $the_query = new WP_Query($the_args);
        ?>
        <?php if ($the_query-> have_posts ()) :?>
          <h2>attachments</h2>
          <ul>
            <?php while ($the_query-> have_posts ()) : $the_query-> the_post(); ?>
              <li><?php the_date();?> - <a
                href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title()?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); // reseteamos el query?>
    <?php  
      // los comments (el display author va variando según las preferencias del usuario)
    $args = array(
      'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
    );
    $comments = get_comments($args);
    ?>
    <?php if (!empty($comments)) :?>
      <h2>comments</h2>
      <ul>
        <?php foreach($comments as $comment) : ?>
          <li><?php echo($comment->comment_author .
          ' - ' . $comment->comment_content); ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

      <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="wp-content"><?php the_content(); // el contenido de la página ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); // footer del wordpress ?>
```

son cuatro queries una de posts, otra de paginas, una de attachments, y por último la de comentarios. en las tres primeras va cambiando el `post_type` y en el caso de adjuntos el `post_status`, la última la hacemos con [get_comments()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

Comment: Grandísimo aporte. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Unos comentarios, puesto que el código, tal como está me daba error. Las correcciones que he metido son:
if($current_user->ID != 0);  ?> (poner ;)
Las siguientes líneas de código, que están justo antes de <div class="wp-content">......, hay que eliminarlas para que no de error la ejecución del código:
<?php endif; ?> 
      <?php endif; ?>
Una duda: ¿el siguiente código que función tiene? ¿mostrar el contenido de la página? Cuando lo elimino, no afecta al resultado de lo que visualizo.
<div class="wp-content"><?php the_content(); // el contenido de la página ?></div>

Comment: En mi web, en cada post hay un video y sus comentarios. Este código genera un enlace al post, pero lo que me gustaría es que se mostrara la miniatura del video y, haciendo clic en ella, fuera al post. Luego tendría que ir creando <div> para distribuir los video en la página. Los videos se incrustan de Youtube (o los podría subir el usuario), con el siguiente shortcode:
[video src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEBEbB50FXI" autoplay="on"]
[youtube_view_count id="fEBEbB50FXI"] visualizaciones
Disculpa, no se si es mucho pedir.